# Setting field of Access table using VBA from form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to set a value of a field from a subroutine which I'm calling from an event handler. I'm simply doing `width = 5`

However, the field value isn't changed. However I can do `height = 5` and the field value is set as expected. The field value for `width` remains unchanged at `12186`.

I've tried changing the field name to `image_width` to no avail.

The form has neither controls `height` nor `width`.

What am I doing wrong / why is this one field not changing. I've tried deleting the field and recreating, and I don't see anything on this field that limits the setting of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every form has an inbuilt property `.Width` so you can't use that for a field name.

A form doesn't have `.Height`, since this is a property of the form sections.

`image_width` shold work, though. Are you sure you edited all relevant settings?
i.e. Table field name, form field Name, form field Controlsource, VBA code?

Comment: If only width was listed as a reserved keyword! As for image_width not working, there seems to be a cache of field names that are made by VBA Access. It seems the only way I can set fields that are renamed / added from a form is by copying the form and using that new form.